# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] "Could not connect"

Tags: php, soap, centos

I have a php web site that used to work running on Centos 6.2 but I cannot make it work on Centos 7.

I have Apache 2.4.6 with php 5.4.16

The problem I am having is that php SoapClient gives me a Soap Exception "Could not connect" and my Soap Server is on the same server as my http server. I tried with the server ip address and with 127.0.0.1 and it still does not work.

So I made a simple php test file (test.php) to eliminate all the complexity of my web server

What I don't understand is that it only fails if I run the php file from an HTTP request. (http://my-server/test-soap.php)

If I run the php file from the command line, it works. (php test-soap.php)

If I test with Curl is works. If I use Soap-UI from my Mac (remote machine) it works.

Also, if I run tcpdump , I don't even see php trying to connect. (no packet at all)

Any idea ?

This is the test code.

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
        echo "Running from CLI\n";
        $nl="\n";
        $_SERVER = array (
                'SERVER_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
                'PHP_AUTH_USER' => '',
                'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '',
        );
} else {
        $nl="<br/>\n";
    // Not in cli-mode
}
echo "Start".$nl;
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
$http_port       =  80;
$ems_soap_port   =  8003;
$ems_addr        = "127.0.0.1";
$soap_target_ems = "https://$ems_addr:$ems_soap_port";
$wsdl_target_ems = "http://$ems_addr:$http_port/wsdl/gccpa.wsdl";
$uri_ems         = "urn:gccpa";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
          'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
        ));
$client  = new SoapClient( $wsdl_target_ems, array(
          'stream_context' => $context,
          'exceptions'=> true,
          'location'  => $soap_target_ems ,
          'uri'       => $uri_ems,
          'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
          'trace'     => true ) );
try
{
    $getnodesResult = $client->__soapCall( 'gccpa-getnodes',
        array( 'parameters' => array('sessionId' => 0, 'sysId' => 1) ) );
    echo "Soap Successull".$nl;
}
catch(SoapFault $exception)
{
   echo 'gccpa:'.'getnodes  exception: '. $exception ;
   unset($client);
}
?>
```

Comment: After more testing, I noticed that the problem was the port. It seems that apache or php or php-soap is restricting the number of ports that can be used for Soap Request. 
I made some test and it works with any port from 80 to 89, port 443 works too. But besides that it is not even trying to connect. 
Again it is not something that is filtered at the system level because it works from command line, curl, .. (iptables and firewalld are stopped)
I did a quick port forwarding with socat from port 81 to 8003 and it fixed the issue. 
I would still prefer a neater solution.

Comment: Finally it was SeLinux blocking ports. 
This was a good conversation with myself.